# Accent conflict in UNIQUE column with COLLATE e.g. utf8_swedish_ci

Tags: mysql, unique, collation

I have question about accents in UNIQUE key columns with specific collation.

I have table where *Character set* is *utf8*. And I have column *surname* where collate is **utf8_czech_ci** - it is not UNIQUE key yet.

```
`surname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Surname' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci'
```

In this table I store two testing names "*i*" and "*í*" LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE.

### Problem

When I try to make this column *UNIQUE* I got following error message

```
SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry 'í' for key
```

NOTE that when I change collate of 'surname' to **utf8_bin**, the UNIQUE key can be created. Other collation such as **utf8_swedish_ci, utf8_spanish_ci, utf8_polish_ci** returns same error such **utf8_czech_ci**.

### Question

I thought that collation affect only order of returned records and not real "meaning" of data value. Different data should be stored as different and unique regardless on collation - or not(?) Could somebody explain this behavior?

### My system

I have MySQL 5.6 on WinXP. Character settings of MySQL is:

```
mysql> show variables like '%character_set%';

"character_set_client"  "utf8"
"character_set_connection"  "utf8"
"character_set_database"    "utf8"
"character_set_filesystem"  "binary"
"character_set_results" "utf8"
"character_set_server"  "utf8"
"character_set_system"  "utf8"
"character_sets_dir"    "c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\"
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You will love this: [MySQL Charset/Collate](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll)

Comment: Very nice reading. Thanks Ravinder!